# How to produce phi instruction in clang for llvm ir?

Tags: c, assembly, optimization, clang, llvm

I am trying to understand the llvm optimization. I do this by writing C code and converting into LLVM IR and reading produced code. Now as far as i understand, phi node needs the return of the block so that it can know what registers to use. So the following function is a good example for producing phi.

```
int fib(int a)
{
  if(a < 3)
    return 1;
  else
    return (fib(a-1) + fib(a-2));
}
```

Clang 10 produced the following IR code :

```
define dso_local i32 @fib(i32 %0) #0 {
  %2 = alloca i32, align 4
  %3 = alloca i32, align 4
  store i32 %0, i32* %3, align 4
  %4 = load i32, i32* %3, align 4
  %5 = icmp slt i32 %4, 3
  br i1 %5, label %6, label %7

6:                                                ; preds = %1
  store i32 1, i32* %2, align 4
  br label %15

7:                                                ; preds = %1
  %8 = load i32, i32* %3, align 4
  %9 = sub nsw i32 %8, 1
  %10 = call i32 @fib(i32 %9)
  %11 = load i32, i32* %3, align 4
  %12 = sub nsw i32 %11, 2
  %13 = call i32 @fib(i32 %12)
  %14 = add nsw i32 %10, %13
  store i32 %14, i32* %2, align 4
  br label %15

15:                                               ; preds = %7, %6
  %16 = load i32, i32* %2, align 4
  ret i32 %16
}
```

However, C blocks explicitly returns values since C is an imperative language. In a language like Rust/ocaml etc, we would know that the last expression is also the return value but in C such concept doesn't even exist or needed. I have played around with couple of other examples, and i am unable to make the clang to produce phi instruction.

Which makes me wonder. Either Clang dont leverage phi instruction for C language because of the C features or I am the one who cannot make the compiler produce it.

I wonder if anyone give me an idea or maybe an example about how to produce phi instruction and related optimisations for C language.

Comment: Enable optimizations and you'll get a phi in your code. Note that, while in this example the value of the phi node happens to also be the return value of the function, there's no inherent connection between phi nodes and return values in general. Also note that blocks don't have return values, functions do.

Comment: I'm not an expert, but I thought phi usually came from loops.  This function doesn't have a loop; it executes straight through (with the `if` conditional), if you think of the recursive calls like any other function call.  And the whole point of recursion is that it is perfectly correct to do so.  Optimization might allow the compiler to optimize the recursion into a loop and then you'd see a phi.  But if you rewrite fib with an iterative algorithm using a loop, I expect you'll see phi with or without optimization.

Comment: @NateEldredge Both loops and if statements can produce phi nodes, but only with optimizations enabled. Without optimizations, clang never generates phi nodes because variables will just be loaded and stored every time they're accessed. The reason that OP's code will have a phi node (with optimizations) is just because the generated code will have a single return statement, so the phi node unifies the value from the two branches of the if. The recursion will still be there.

Comment: Compilers that use LLVM don't need to construct "proper SSA" themselves, they can use variables in memory and let the `mem2reg` pass transform them into SSA-variables.

Comment: @sepp2k oooowww. i thought, Clang generates the code and interpret optimization related code later on. You save me a lot time. Thank you.

Comment: @sepp2k i got it and achieve what i want both with clang and my code base works like a charm. thanks again for the insight

Comment: "i thought, Clang generates the code and interpret optimization related code later on" It does. When you run `clang -O1 -S -emit-llvm` it will first generate the code without optimizations, then apply optimizations to it (via LLVM) and then output the optimized LLVM assembly. As Harold said, clang itself never generates any phi node, but lets LLVM's mem2reg phase take care of that. Either way the result is that the generated LLVM assembly will contain phi nodes if and only if you invoke clang with ...

Comment: ... optimizations enabled (you could also run `mem2reg` yourself via `opt`, but you'd have to remove anti-optimziation flags from the assembly first).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```c
void use(int); 
int f1();
int f2();
void test(int i) { 
    int x; 
    if (i) x = f1(); else x = f2();
    use(x); 
}
```

Run `clang -cc1 -disable-O0-optnone foo.c -emit-llvm -O0`, which generates the `foo.ll` with O0 optimization code in LLVM IR format. Note that the `-disable0O0-optnone` is important otherwise llvm `opt` tool will refuse to optimize the code further, which means you will never see the `phi` node.

You will see the `O0` IR is:

```
define void @test(i32 noundef %i) #0 {
entry:
  %i.addr = alloca i32, align 4
  %x = alloca i32, align 4
  store i32 %i, ptr %i.addr, align 4
  %0 = load i32, ptr %i.addr, align 4
  %tobool = icmp ne i32 %0, 0
  br i1 %tobool, label %if.then, label %if.else

if.then:                                          ; preds = %entry
  %call = call i32 @f1()
  store i32 %call, ptr %x, align 4
  br label %if.end

if.else:                                          ; preds = %entry
  %call1 = call i32 @f2()
  store i32 %call1, ptr %x, align 4
  br label %if.end

if.end:                                           ; preds = %if.else, %if.then
  %1 = load i32, ptr %x, align 4
  call void @use(i32 noundef %1)
  ret void
}
```

Then, run it with `O1` level:

```bash
$ clang -cc1 foo.c -emit-llvm -O1
```

the output IR is:

```
; Function Attrs: nounwind
define void @test(i32 noundef %i) local_unnamed_addr #0 {
entry:
  %tobool.not = icmp eq i32 %i, 0
  br i1 %tobool.not, label %if.else, label %if.then

if.then:                                          ; preds = %entry
  %call = tail call i32 @f1() #2
  br label %if.end

if.else:                                          ; preds = %entry
  %call1 = tail call i32 @f2() #2
  br label %if.end

if.end:                                           ; preds = %if.else, %if.then
  %x.0 = phi i32 [ %call, %if.then ], [ %call1, %if.else ]
  tail call void @use(i32 noundef %x.0) #2
  ret void
}
```

I wrote a blog about it, and it carries the way how to use llvm `opt` to optimize the generate `O0` code with the `phi` node by `mem2reg` pass. Hope it could help you a lot:
https://yuchenx.pages.dev/blog/llvm/llvm-control-flow-and-phi-node/

Comment: great answer. but i cant read your website. it gives "PR_CONNECT_RESET_ERROR"

Comment: I hosted my website in the cloudflare and I could access it in Singapore, please check whether it's your network issue. 0.0